# how to translate angular datePipe's dates with moment.js?

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular11, date-pipe, angular-date-format

I  have this version of packages:

```
"@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.2.9",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
```

I am using angular datePipe  `| date: 'MMM d, y'`   format,  which is mediumDate.   I want  to  translate  it  to other language.  For  example  Instead of `Jun 15, 2015` , I want  to  be  'ივნ 15,2015".

`shared.module.ts`

```
export function culture() {
    const locale = localStorage.getItem('culture');
    return locale ? locale.substr(0, locale.indexOf('-')) : 'ka';
}
 providers: [
        { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: culture() },
        { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
        { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS }
    ]
```

`app.module.ts`

```
moment.locale(culture());
```

Also I use   angular material datepicker  and  it  translates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added in the  shared  module

```
import ka from '@angular/common/locales/ka';
registerLocaleData(ka);
providers: [
   DatePipe,
]
```

and  Add alseo  localized date pipe  which transform  dates according to currentLanguage.

there is  solution     link[solution](https://decodedscript.com/how-to-create-localized-date-pipe-in-angular-12/)